# postman "this file isn't in your working directory"

Tags: postman

I'm using postman to upload a file.  I've set my working directory according to the instructions, but but when I hover over the selected file, I'm still getting: "this file isn't in your working directory."  Any suggestions how to solve this?

Comment: It's just a warning bug but functionality works ,

Answer (score 3):

https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/9605

Raised an issue for the same,  if you set the directory correctly or have enabled the below flag. THe file will be send correctly . The tool tip is just a warning message which looks like an issue for which a ticket have been raised

[image]