# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'path')

Tags: node.js

**route file**

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, './uploads');
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, new Date().toISOString() + file.originalname);
  },
});

const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
  // reject a file
  if (file.mimetype === 'image/jpg' || file.mimetype === 'image/png') {
    cb(null, true);
  } else {
    cb(null, false);
  }
};

const upload = multer({
  storage: storage,
  limits: {
    fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 5,
  },
  fileFilter: fileFilter,
});

router.post('/hiring', upload.single('resume'), (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.file);
  const hiring = new Hiring({
    _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
    username: req.body.username,
    email: req.body.gender,
    mobile: req.body.mobile,
    resume: req.file.path,
  });
  hiring
    .save()
    .then((result) => {
      console.log(result);
      res.status(200).json({
        message: 'Created user successfully',
        createdUser: {
          _id: result._id,
          username: result.username,
          email: result.email,
          mobile: result.mobile,
          resume: result.resume,
        },
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500).json({
        error: err,
      });
    });
});
```

I am trying to post data in database through postman but it is getting error 'path undefined'. I tried to change folder path like './uploads/', '/uploads', 'uploads/' and 'uploads' but the problem is not solving.

**error**

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'path')
```

please give the solution for this problem.

Comment: Can you post the code where you are setting your route middlewares?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vue Frontend - Multer Express - Req.File is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71686602/vue-frontend-multer-express-req-file-is-undefined). TL;DR don't use the callback version of `destination`, just use `destination: __dirname + "/uploads"`

Answer (score -1):

It appears `req.file` is undefined. which itself meant you are not uploading file via postman.

You have to attach file in postman with 'resume' as keyword after selecting mutlipart in body section.

[check this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGm4I.png)

With [dothttp](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ShivaPrasanth.dothttp-code)
It would look like this

```
POST 'http://localhost:3000/hiring'
multipart(
    'resume'< '<replace path to the resume here>',
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, in postman am getting this 'This file isn't in your working directory. Teammates you share this request with won't be able to use this file. To make collaboration easier you can setup your working directory in Settings.' after selecting an image

Comment: It is just a warning. you can ignore and proceed with that.

Comment: for more information you can check there https://stackoverflow.com/a/66180598/18530879

Comment: go through this screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGm4I.png